# Is it possible to append to an existing Feathers format file?

Tags: python, pandas, feather

I am working on a very huge dataset with 20 million+ records. I am trying to save all that data into a feathers format for faster access and also append as I proceed with me analysis.

Is there a way to append pandas dataframe to an existing feathers format file?

Answer (score 5):

Feather files are intended to be written at once. Thus appending to them is not a supported use case.

Instead I would recommend to you for such a large dataset to write the data into *individual* Apache Parquet files using `pyarrow.parquet.write_table` or `pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet` and read the data also back into Pandas using `pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset` or `pandas.read_parquet`. These functions can treat a collection of Parquet files as a single dataset that is read at once into a single DataFrame.